# Who is the Serpent in Genesis?

Tags: parashat-bereishit, sheidim-demons

I've read in the book "The Essential Zohar" by Rav Philip Berg that the Serpent was none other than the "Klipah"mentionned by name in Isiaiah 34:14.

Yet Rabbi Mordechai Kraft appeared in a youtube video saying that the Serpent was actually incarnated by Satan.

Who is this Serpent ?

Comment: Can you cite this youtube video?

Comment: @DoubleAA, sure, I hope it's permissible to post it here:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_AHco824RDI

Comment: Can you explain the statement "the 'klipah' mentioned by name"? My text doesn't have the word "klipah" in 34:14. Also, have you looked for any more traditional explanations before moving to mystical understandings?  http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9243/do-religious-jews-generally-believe-the-serpent-of-gan-eden-was-satan

Comment: @Danno According to the book I mentioned above, the"Klipah" was a nickname given in the Zohar by the entity mentioned by name in 34:14. It says we should never mention her name. Anyone I will go ahead and say it...Lilith !

Comment: @Danno, It was the first time I read about her in a book. I have never read so far about it in a traditional commentaries before

Comment: @mil jumping to Lilith seems extreme as the concept of Lilith is complex on its own https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/jsource/judaica/ejud_0002_0013_0_12540.html the mystical idea of the Klippot is very complex (as is anything mystical) and the serpent is complex. You needn't jump all the way to this confusing combination of ideas.

Comment: Yalkut Reuvaini Braishis says that Satan got jealous and came down from heaven in the form of a snakes shadow. The snake came and protected this shadow. 

> ותאמר האשה אל הנחש וגו', מלאכי השרת היו מקלסין לאדם בגן עדן, וראה
> סמא"ל בשמים וקינא בו, וירד מן השמים כדמות צל של נחש, הנחש נראה והצל
> עליו

Comment: @GershonGold, as far as I know, Satan doesn't have a free will. Did G-d allow him to do that according to Yalkut Reuvaini Braishis ?

Comment: As far as I know Satan has a job, which is to cause people to sin.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the question here is "Who is this Serpent [viz the snake in Genesis]?" and question in [the preexisting question](/q/9243) is the same. I move to close this as a duplicate. cc @GershonGold

Comment: @msh210 does it become a discrete question because it asks about an opinion not reflected in the others, and introduces a concept not part of the others?

Comment: See this for "R'" Philip Berg's problematic approach to kabbalah: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/44662/4504

Comment: @Danno, not AFAICT. If that opinion is correct, it can be an answer to the preexisting question. I'm casting the 4th and 5th votes to close as duplicate thereof.